# how to exit a python script immediately without delay

Tags: python, powershell, exit

I am calling a ~500 lines python script from MS powershell with two argument values. I want to exit the python script if `sys.argv[1] > sys.argv[2]`. The `if` condition is in the beginning of the script.

However, `(time.time() - start_time)` always shows a similar time until exit as when the script is executing as a whole.

I have tried `os._exit(0)`, `os.exit()`, `quit()`, `sys.exit()`, all with similar results.

Isn't there a way to terminate and return to batch immediately, similar to `quit` in batch that works instantaneously?

Here is the beginning of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Start clock
import time
import datetime as dt
start_time = time.time()

# Import modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import time
import sys
import glob
import csv
import glob
import fileinput
import os
import io
import shutil
import decimal
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker

from business_calendar import Calendar, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR
from datetime import datetime
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from backtest import Strategy, Portfolio
from sys import exit
from decimal import Decimal
from colorama import init
from shutil import copyfile
from datetime import date, timedelta as td

init()

# Definition of argument values
num1 = int(sys.argv[1])
num2 = int(sys.argv[2])
num123 = datetime.strptime(sys.argv[3], "%Y-%m-%d")
num321 = datetime.strptime(sys.argv[4], "%Y-%m-%d")
stock = sys.argv[5]
total = 'total'

# Date conversions
num987 = num123.strftime('%Y%m%d')
num888 = int(num987)
num789 = num321.strftime('%Y%m%d')
num999 = int(num789)

if num1 > num2:
```

Comment: How much time has passed in each case? If it's a really short amount of time, the script itself might just be a really short component, and instead most of it is the initial setup and launching the interpreter.  Can you show us the script up to your `if` condition?

Comment: running time (complete): ~1,8 sec; running time (exit condition) ~1,7 sec

Comment: This has nothing to do with [batch-file].

Comment: This is a wild guess, and may be completely wrong, but does it work if you change the condition to `if int(sys.argv[1]) > int(sys.argv[2]):`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Consider the code *before* you exit.  You are importing 19 modules, which probably import many more, and some might execute other code on import.  These are going to be imported whether you exit or not.  Do you need all these modules to have global scope?  You can easily test if this is a significant overhead by placing your test and exit before you import (as a test).  Yes, I know that breaks PEP008.

Comment: Not related to your question but you could (should) also use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html)

Comment: Another thought, are any of the modules installed on network drives?

Comment: @cdarke many thanks, that did it! down to 0.001 seconds. many thanks!

Comment: @sudonym: moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
raise SystemExit
```

There is also another "os" function - `os._exit` - which should terminate immediately, because it terminates at the C level

Comment: Also `os._exit` does not execute any tidy-up code that might be in the modules.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the code before you exit. You are importing 19 modules, which probably import many more, and some might execute other code on import. These are going to be imported and executed whether you exit or not.

You can easily test if this is a significant overhead by placing your test and exit before you import (as a test).

Do you need all these modules to have global scope?

Yes, I know that breaks PEP008: 
"*imports are always put at the top of the file*"

But: "...*sometimes style guide recommendations just aren't applicable...*"

I suggest you comment your reasons for having code before the imports.

Answer (score -1):

I've always used:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Start clock
import time
import datetime as dt

# Import modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import time
import sys
import glob
import csv
import glob
import fileinput
import os
import io
import shutil
import decimal
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker

from business_calendar import Calendar, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR
from datetime import datetime
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from backtest import Strategy, Portfolio
from sys import exit
from decimal import Decimal
from colorama import init
from shutil import copyfile
from datetime import date, timedelta as td

if __name__ == '__main__':

    start_time = time.time()
    init()

    # Definition of argument values
    num1 = int(sys.argv[1])
    num2 = int(sys.argv[2])

    if num1 > num2:
        sys.exit(1)

    num123 = datetime.strptime(sys.argv[3], "%Y-%m-%d")
    num321 = datetime.strptime(sys.argv[4], "%Y-%m-%d")
    stock = sys.argv[5]
    total = 'total'

    # Date conversions
    num987 = num123.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    num888 = int(num987)
    num789 = num321.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    num999 = int(num789)
```

The `if __name__ == '__main__':` feels more pythonic to me!

Comment: This is more suitable as a comment. By chance, it probably answers the OP's question by moving  `start_time = time.time()`. If you highlight that, it would be more suitable